# Wordpress images not displaying (Woocommerce)

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with my WordPress site after I started using a plugin to minify the css. Products images don't show up (WooCommerce plugin displays the images). An image/gif appears first and blocks my image.

This is my website: https://geerdesfromage.com/

The HTML code should be like that :

```
<img src="https://geerdesfromage.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/gouda-affiné-1-600x556.jpg" width="600" height="556" alt="gouda-affiné-1" class="jetpack-lazy-image jetpack-lazy-image--handled" data-lazy-loaded="1" scale="0">
```

But it appears like that :

```
<img src="image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" width="600" height="556" data-src="https://geerdesfromage.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/gouda-affiné-1-600x556.jpg" alt="gouda-affiné-1" class="jetpack-lazy-image jetpack-lazy-image--handled" data-lazy-loaded="1" scale="0">
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: It looks like there is a plugin who converts the images to base64 data strings. However, the src cant contain that many characters. Thats why the data string is way too short and doesn't contain a full image. Try to disable your lazy load plugin, maybe the normal data src will work.

Comment: I checked again, sometimes it works but your minify script is getting an error:
https://geerdesfromage.com/wp-content/cache/minify/0fef6.js?x19535

Comment: It has something to do with your ssl certificate. Check this link
https://github.com/mrclay/minify/issues/619
its the same error with the same image problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it doesn't work all the time because of the minify script that gives errors

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /homepages/32/d724101584/htdocs/clickandbuilds/geerdesfromage/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/Minify/Minify/JS/ClosureCompiler.php on line 91.

On the [following thread](https://github.com/mrclay/minify/issues/619) I can see Google has recently disabled access to the compiler via non-ssl access. You do have ssl access so make sure every request is made with https and not http.

Comment: Thank you for help Benidorm, do you think is good if I delete this file via ftp?

Comment: I dont think so, you can try to rename it. But a better solution will be to disable the minify plugin. However I think the plugin can work if you request all files with https. For example your logo is requested without https

Comment: Will do it, have a nice day!